# Where can I use threads to improve these methods?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

Okay so for my project in my CSC330 class I am supposed to use threads to quickly find the answer to queries in a massive data set. Each item in the array is a user and the string is a collection of sites they visited on a website identified by number.

Example (the array is String users[])

users[1] = "1 4 5 7" users[2] = "1 2 7 17 10" users[3] = "6"

The queries are:

- are there more than ___ users who looked at X
- What percent of users looked at X
- Are there more users who looked at X than Y
- How many users viewed X ____ number of times
- What percent of users looked at X more than Y

there are about a million users in this array and we had to solve the following queries without threads on a smaller scale version of the data for testing. All of mine work. Now I need to switch to the massive text file and I need to use threads to increase the speed. I'm wondering where it would be beneficial and how I could implement these threads. I will supply my code for solving each query. I'm thinking that I could use multiple threads to go through parts of the array at the same time but I'm not sure how to execute this.

```
    public boolean query1(String num, String pageName){
    if(num == null){
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        int userCount = 0;
        int pageNum = convert(pageName);
        System.out.println(pageNum);
        String pageNumString = Integer.toString(pageNum);
        System.out.println(pageNumString);
        for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++ )
        {
            for(String entry : users[i].split(" "))
            {
                if(entry.equals(pageNumString))
                {
                    userCount++;
                    break;
                }   
            }
    }
    if(userCount > Integer.parseInt(num)){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
    }
    }
public float query2(String pageName){
    int userCount = 0;
    int pageNum = convert(pageName);
    String pageNumString = Integer.toString(pageNum);
    for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++ )
    {
        for(String entry : users[i].split(" "))
        {
            if(entry.equals(pageNumString))
            {
                userCount++;
                break;
            }   

        }
    }
    float percentage = (userCount*100.0f)/users.length;
    return percentage;  
}
public boolean query3(String pageName, String pageName2){
    int userCount1 = 0;
    int userCount2 = 0;
    String pageNumString = Integer.toString(convert(pageName));
    String pageNumString2 = Integer.toString(convert(pageName2));
    for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++ )
    {
        for(String entry : users[i].split(" "))
        {
            if(entry.equals(pageNumString))
            {
                userCount1++;
                break;
            }   
        }
        for(String entry : users[i].split(" "))
        {
            if(entry.equals(pageNumString2))
            {
                userCount2++;
                break;
            }   
        }
    }
    return userCount1 > userCount2;

}
public int query4(String pageName, int numTimes){
    int userCount = 0;
    String pageNumString = Integer.toString(convert(pageName));
    for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++ )//runs through each user
    {   int pageCount = 0;
        for(String entry : users[i].split(" "))// runs through each user's pages
        {
            if(entry.equals(pageNumString))
            {
                pageCount++;                // each time page is found page count increments 1
            }   
        }                                  // once done running through user's pages
        if(pageCount == numTimes){         // check if the number of pages is equal to the number given
            userCount++;                   // if so increment userCount
        }
    }
    return userCount;
}
public float query5(String pageName, String pageName2){
    int viewedMore = 0;
    int userCount1 = 0;
    int userCount2 = 0;
    String pageNumString = Integer.toString(convert(pageName));
    String pageNumString2 = Integer.toString(convert(pageName2));
    for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++ )
    {
        for(String entry : users[i].split(" ")){
            userCount1 = 0;
            userCount2 = 0;
            if(entry.equals(pageNumString))
            {
                userCount1++;
                break;
            }   
        }
        for(String entry : users[i].split(" "))
        {
            if(entry.equals(pageNumString2))
            {
                userCount2++;
                break;
            }   
        }
        if(userCount1 > userCount2){
            viewedMore++;
        }
    }
    return viewedMore*100.0f/users.length;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least, in `query3` and `query5` you can spawn off threads for each of the two inner for-loops; there's no reason they must be run sequentially. And for any of the query functions, you can certainly split the array into sections. Since your data is growing large, that approach will most likely be faster than iterating over the data with the *main* thread.

I would suggest providing the threads contiguous segments (e.g. index 0 to N-1; N to N+N-1 etc). This previous [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8345274/2356554) provides good reasoning why such an approach is most efficient. Once you get something working, you can play around with the number of threads to optimize.

### edit to address your comment below

One approach would be to implement the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), such that each of your Query are interchangeable across a client, where an `executeQuery()` call is the interface method. Think of having a client's call look something like

```
interface Query {
    boolean executeQuery();
}

// client code...
Client client = new Client(...);
client.setQuery(new Query3(String num, String pageNum));
client.query(); // calls query.executeQuery();
```

Within the concrete `Query` classes, you can define individual behaviors of what the threads would do. This is a rough example:

```
public Query3 implements Query { 
    Query3(String pageNum`, String pageNum2) {
        this.pageNum1=pageNum1;
        this.pageNum2=pageNum2;
    }

    boolean executeQuery() {
        for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++ ) {
            SearchThread first = new SearchThread(pageNum1);
            SearchThread second = new SearchThread(pageNum2);
            first.run();
            second.run();
        }
        first.join();
        second.join();
        return first.userCount > second.userCount;
   }

SearchThread extends Thread {
    String pageNumString;
    int userCount;
    SearchThread(String pageNumString) {
        this.pageNumString=pageNumString;
    }
    public void run() {
        // do your search over this segment of the array, adding up userCounts
    }
```

Here is another [StackOverflow question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9437/why-does-this-programs-speed-not-increase) that describes how to run multiple threads over a single array, with some boilerplate code to use.

Comment: I understand this abstractly, how would I implement this though? I understand how to use the run() method from implementing runnable but how can I use multiple threads? It seems like I would need more than one run() method?